# What is the best way of loading structured text resource file in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a structured data file. I create the file so format can be flexible. For now it is a custom text format but it can be xml or Json as well. My intention is to load it all in Client side and then put it to an internal memory structure. What is the correct way of getting a resource file from server and parse in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using just JSON?

Do this on the server:

```
import 'dart:json';

var obj = {'foo': 'bar'};
var output = JSON.stringify(obj); // Send the output to the client.
```

then on the client you do:

```
import 'dart:json';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonedObject); // obj now holds a {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Or did I understood the question wrong?

Comment: I am assuming how data is transmitted to client is happening behind the scenes with this? Sorry that I am a little rusty on the client side issues.

Comment: Ok I will do something similar. I will just put the json file in a URL and get it from there directly. Hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: Usually you `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to encode/decode messages. Where you place these messages is up to you. If you are using Dart's `HttpRequest` class under `dart:html` for instance, then you can encode the message and place it within the request and retrieve it on the server.